# Can't install Office 2010 due to Microsoft Setup Bootstrapper telling me to ask an adult

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

Let's start with the basics:

This account I am using to install my software is the main, listed as an administrator who is over 18 and is not nor has ever been listed as a child account.

I'm running Windows 10 professional 64 bit. I have tried to install both as Windows 10 and in Windows 7 compatibility.

[image: my stupid error message]

I've seen lots of posts for people in the past having an issue with bootstrapper freezing, but since that's not my issue I didn't want to go fiddling with the registry.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Curiously, what does it do if you “ask by email?”

Comment: Have you tried any of this here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security-insiderplat_pc/family-safety-help/903fa963-76be-40fd-80cd-2e69f65ffe74